# Type comparison in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm still just learning the basics of Haskell, and I've tried to find an answer to this simple question, so I apologize in advance, because I'm sure it's simple.

Given:

```
data Fruit = Fruit| Apple | Orange
    deriving (Show, Eq)

a = Apple
```

How do I check if some a is a Fruit?

Comment: I'd be interested in knowing exactly why you want this.

Comment: @sclv:  Given the program above, a == Apple returns True.  a == Fruit returns False.  I just want to know how I tell if some variable is a Fruit.  Nothing complicated.  Apple == Fruit also returns false.  Maybe it's confusing because the data and type constructor are both the same name.  Ok, so replace data Fruit with data FruitType ..., I still can't find a way to do some kind of check that a is related to FruitType.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Assuming you really meant *type* comparison, the simple answer is "you can't".  Haskell is statically typed, so the check is done at compile-time, not run-time.  So, if you have a function like this:

```
foo :: Fruit -> Bool
foo Apple = True
foo x     = False
```

The answer of whether or not `x` is a Fruit will always be "yes".

What you might be trying to do is find out what data constructor a given value was constructed with.  To do that, use pattern matching:

```
fruitName :: Fruit -> String
fruitName Fruit  = "Fruit"
fruitName Apple  = "Apple"
fruitName Orange = "Orange"
```

By the way, if you're using GHCi, and you want to know the type of something, use `:t`

```
> let a = 123
> :t a
a :: Integer
>
```

Comment: @Joey Adams:  I have an Apple, and I want a function that will return the data constructor, Fruit (as opposed to the type constructor, Apple) ... so from the sounds of it, I'd still have to use pattern matching and make a function myself (that is, there's nothing in Prelude?), like your example, but with fruitName Apple = "Fruit", instead of fruitName Apple = "Apple", to determine the data constructor name?

Comment: @Richard Hein: You can use `Typeable` to archive this. But it's evil.

Comment: @Joey Adams:  To clarify, if I load my little program in my question in GHCi and do a :type a, I get "a :: Fruit".  I want a function that returns the same thing :type does in GHCi.

Comment: @Richard Hein: Inspect `Data.Typeable` for this.

Comment: @FUZxxl:  Ok, I'll check it out ... but why is it "evil"? :)

Comment: @Richard Hein: It let's you bypass one of the strongest type-systems in the world. Even if it's safe to use, things usually bacome more complicated afterwards. Think of a solution which doesn't needs this.

Comment: There's nothing evil about Typeable in itself. Dynamic is arguably a bit of a trickier issue. But you can define your own typeable on the cheap in a perfectly principled way. `class MyTypeable a where getType :: String`. `Data.Typeable` is like this except just much better.