# Haskell pattern match on type

Tags: haskell

Is there any way of doing something like this in haskell ?

```
data Fruits = Apple Int | Orange Int deriving (Eq, Show)

basket = [Apple 2, Orange 4]

from_basket t (x:basket) =
    case x of
        (t i) -> i
        _ -> from_basket t basket
```

Now i want to get the 'apple' from the list of fruits ( basket )

```
from_basket Apple basket
```

Without an explicit pattern match

```
case x of
    Apple i -> ...
    Orange i -> ...
    _ ->
```

Comment: Appears to be an almost exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4273702/type-comparison-in-haskell

Comment: @Carl: I don't think it's _almost exact_. In the other question the OP wants to check whether a variable is of some type (which is decided at compile time). Here the question is what constructor of a constant type was invoked (which is decided at run time).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

One way would be to define your own helper function `isApple` and then do filtering:

```
isApple (Apple _) = True
isApple _         = False

getApples = filter isApple
```

Pattern matching is the tool of your choice, I don't know whether you can simplify this any further. But apart from some dirty template Haskell, I don't see any other way.

Comment: This returns `[Fruits]` though, not `Int`.

Comment: @delnan: so you can chain it to get the `Int`: `head . map (\Apple i -> i) . filter isApple`

Comment: This strikes me as slightly cleaner than the `Maybe` approach in this case, and having access to all the apples in the basket, or `[]` if there are none, may also be useful.

Answer (score 12):

The other answers have explained why it won't work as is, but as far as alternatives go, wanting to do something like that is often a sign that your data types should look something more like this:

```
data FruitName = Apple | Orange deriving (Eq, Show)
data Fruits = Fruits FruitName Int deriving (Eq, Show)
```

...in which case the desired function becomes trivial.

Comment: Could you elaborate for those that fail to see the triviality in the example?

Answer (score 5):

You can accomplish something similar to this by defining selector functions

```
getApple :: Fruits -> Maybe Int
getApple (Apple x) = Just x
getApple _ = Nothing

getOrange :: Fruits -> Maybe Int
getOrange (Orange x) = Just x
getOrange _ = Nothing

fromBasket selector [] = Nothing
fromBasket selector (x:basket) =
    case selector x of
        Just x -> Just x
        Nothing -> fromBasket selector basket
```

Now you can do

```
> fromBasket getApple basket
Just 2

> fromBasket getOrange basket
Just 4
```

This assumes that your constructors all take similar arguments. It also returns `Nothing` if the desired fruit type was not in the basket.

Comment: You already use `Maybe` - why not make `fromBasket :: [Fruits] -> Maybe Fruits` too and avoid the "evil" `error`? I.e. `fromBasket selector [] = Nothing` (and I think that has to go first, too).

Comment: Yes, that makes sense here. I've updated the code. The empty list case does not have to come first here, as the `(:)` constructor does not match the `[]`, however placing the empty list case first is considered more idiomatic. Thanks :)